# Reload page after notify shows completely done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, toastr

Anyone here how do I fix my notification? I want to show the notification completely done and then reload the page. Currently, my notification exits fast and not showing completely. I'm using ajax and toastr on this. Thanks so much guys! Really appreciate your help. Here's what I've tried:

```
function InsertOrUpdateExpense() {
    var data = $('#formExpenseTransaction').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : url + 'InsertOrUpdateExpenseTransaction',
        data : data,
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend:function() {
            $('#btn-expense--transaction').html(' <i class="icon-spinner2 spinner"></i>').attr('disabled',true);
        },
        success:function(data) {
            data.success === true ? notify(data.type,data.message) : notify(data.type,data.message);
            var content = data.type == 'info' ? 'Save Changes' : 'Add Expense';
            $('#btn-expense--transaction').html(content +' <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>').attr('disabled',false);
            setTimeout(function() {
                location.reload();
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
}

function notify(type,message) {
    Command: toastr[type](message)
}

function toastr_option() {
    toastr.options = {
        "newestOnTop": true, "progressBar": false, "positionClass": "toast-top-right", "preventDuplicates": true, "showDuration": 300, "hideDuration": 1000, "timeOut": 5000, "extendedTimeOut": 1000, "showEasing": "swing", "hideEasing": "linear", "showMethod": "slideDown", "hideMethod": "slideUp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your location.reload() from inside of setTimeout to an option of toastr, named 'onHidden'.

```
function toastr_option() {
    toastr.options = {
        "newestOnTop": true, "progressBar": false, "positionClass": "toast-top-right", "preventDuplicates": true, "showDuration": 300, "hideDuration": 1000, "timeOut": 5000, "extendedTimeOut": 1000, "showEasing": "swing", "hideEasing": "linear", "showMethod": "slideDown", "hideMethod": "slideUp", onHidden: function(){. location.reload(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this property onHidden, will be executed, when the notification get hidden. So, after a while, page will be refreshed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know toastr, but reading [his documentation](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) you can try with his callback functions.

In his example: `toastr.options.onHidden = function() { console.log('goodbye'); }`

Something like this:

```
function toastr_option() {
    toastr.options = {
        "newestOnTop": true, "progressBar": false, "positionClass": "toast-top-right", "preventDuplicates": true, "showDuration": 300, "hideDuration": 1000, "timeOut": 5000, "extendedTimeOut": 1000, "showEasing": "swing", "hideEasing": "linear", "showMethod": "slideDown", "hideMethod": "slideUp"
    }
    toastr.options.onHidden = function() { location.reload(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can Make it like this**

```
toastr.success(
          'Done',
          'Added Successfully',
        {
          timeOut: 1000,
          fadeOut: 1000,
          onHidden: function () {
            window.location.reload();
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

For React user using toast

```
toast.success(errorMessage,
{   
  onClose: () => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      window.location.reload();
    },6000)
}
});
```

The onclose and toast notification will be depending on the timeout. (6000 is 6 seconds)